# Enable db connection access from within a PHP function

Tags: php, function

I have a quick question. I have this file that checks if a password is valid:

Check:

```
<?php
    include('inc/db.php');
    include('inc/functions.php');

    $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

    validateInput($myusername, $mypassword);
?>
```

Function:

```
<?php

        function validateInput($naam, $password) {

            $myusername = stripslashes($naam);
            $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
            $myusername = $conn->real_escape_string($myusername);
            $mypassword = $conn->real_escape_string($mypassword);

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE naam='$myusername' and paswoord='$mypassword'";

                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                      echo "ingelogd";

                    }else{
                        echo "niet ingelogd ";
                    }

       }
?>
```

and

```
<?php
    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    else{
        echo "works<br/><br/>";
    }
```

?>

Now for some reason the validateInput function cant acces the db. it doesnt recognize the $conn var and gives me this fatal error Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in mysite.nl/functions.php on line 12

I have done the includes fine since db.php outputs works on the check.php page. What am I doing wrong, do I need a global var or something?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: you have yo define $conn in  validateInput function.

Comment: You need `$conn` to be made available in the scope of your `validateInput()` function. Maybe adding `global $conn;` in the top of your function would help.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is maybe simple but in fact is very broad, there is plenty solutions out there.

**Few examples:**

## good one - singleton

```
class db extends mysqli {

    static public function get_instance() {
        static $conn = null;
        if($conn == null) {
            $conn = new static($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        }
        return $conn;
    }
}
```

and

```
function validateInput($naam, $password) {

        $myusername = stripslashes($naam);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
        $myusername = db::get_instance()->real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword = db::get_instance()->real_escape_string($mypassword);

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE naam='$myusername' and paswoord='$mypassword'";

                $result = db::get_instance()->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  echo "ingelogd";

                }else{
                    echo "niet ingelogd ";
                }

   }
```

## even better one - singleton with data access layer

```
class db {

    protected $conn;

    static public function get_instance() {
        static $obj = null;
        if($obj == null) {
            $obj = new static();
        }
        return $obj;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        return $this->conn->query($sql);
    }

    public function escape($string) {
        return $this->conn->real_escape_string($string);
    }

    // this is good because you can handle errors etc, add insert/delete/update functions etc.

    public function insert($table_name, $fields) {
         // ..
    }

    public function update($table_name, $data, $where = null, $limit = null) {
         // ..
    }

    public function select($table_name, $where = null, $order_by = null, $limit = null) {
         // ..
    }

    // etc.

}
```

and

```
function validateInput($naam, $password) {
        ..
        $myusername = db::get_instance()->escape($myusername);
        $mypassword = db::get_instance()->escape($mypassword);
        ..
        $result = db::get_instance()->query($sql);
   }
```

you may find lot of premade DB classes in internet

first result from Google - https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

## bad one - globals

```
function validateInput($naam, $password) {

        global $conn; // <-------- HERE

        $myusername = stripslashes($naam);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
        $myusername = $conn->real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword = $conn->real_escape_string($mypassword);

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE naam='$myusername' and paswoord='$mypassword'";

                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  echo "ingelogd";

                }else{
                    echo "niet ingelogd ";
                }

   }
```

## bad one - globals 2

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$GLOBALS['db'] = $conn;
```

and

```
function validateInput($naam, $password) {

        $myusername = stripslashes($naam);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
        $myusername = $GLOBALS['db']->real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword = $GLOBALS['db']->real_escape_string($mypassword);

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE naam='$myusername' and paswoord='$mypassword'";

                $result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  echo "ingelogd";

                }else{
                    echo "niet ingelogd ";
                }

   }
```

## bad one - pass `$conn` as parameter

(as suggested by @LucM)

(why it's bad? because most likely you don't have two databases so it's quite pointless to write code in that way)

```
function validateInput($conn, $naam, $password) {


        $myusername = stripslashes($naam);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
        $myusername = $conn->real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword = $conn->real_escape_string($mypassword);

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE naam='$myusername' and paswoord='$mypassword'";

                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  echo "ingelogd";

                }else{
                    echo "niet ingelogd ";
                }

   }


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    else{
        echo "works<br/><br/>";
    }

..

validateInput($conn, $naam, $password);
```

---

**also it's worth to mention you shouldn't use `stripslashes` and `real_escape_string`. PHP's mysqli module supports [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and it's good practice to use them instead escaping data by yourself.**

Comment: You can also pass a connection as parameter.

Comment: Great thanx! one quick question. in the singleton example. should I include the server name and other connection vars inside the get_instance function?

Comment: @Merijndk it's really up to you, you can make separate file like "db_config.php" with `$username = ".."; " $servername = "..." etc` and include it just before connection so `include "db_config.php"; $conn = new static($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`